# isqrt function ValueError

Tags: python, valueerror

I am trying to figure out a valueerror when I input a negative number in this code. I am trying to  get it to say if a number is positive, negative, odd or even, or a square or not. All numbers work but negative that give back a value error from my ( if isqrt(num) * isqrt(num) == 0 ), because it will only read positive values but how do I input into the last few lines that it must be nonnegative to test isqrt function?

```
from math import isqrt

num = int(input("enter a number: "))
if num > 0:
    print(num, "is positive")
elif num == 0:
    print(num, "is zero")
else:
    print(num, "is negative")

if num % 2 == 0:
    print(num, 'is even')
else:
    print(num, 'is odd')

if isqrt(num) * isqrt(num) == num:
    print(num, 'is square')
else:
    print(num, 'is not square')
```

Comment: Why not precede the sqrt test with a check? Like `if num >= 0 and isqrt(num) * isqrt(num) == num:`?

Comment: Inputs to `isqrt` can not be negative.

Comment: math.isqrt() method in Python is used to get the integer square root of the given non-negative integer value n

Answer (score 1):

ok so I got it to do what i want. All I had to add was the( if num >= 0 and isqrt(num) * isqrt(num) == num: ). so just add the [num >= 0 and] . found by  N. Wouda thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are gettinga `ValueError`, why don't you include the square part inside `if num > 0`?

```
from math import isqrt
def check_sqrt(num):
    if isqrt(num) * isqrt(num) == num:
        print(num, 'is square')
    else:
        print(num, 'is not square')
num = int(input("enter a number: "))
if num > 0:
    print(num, "is positive")
    check_sqrt(num)
elif num == 0:
    print(num, "is zero")
    check_sqrt(num)
else:
    print(num, "is negative")

if num % 2 == 0:
    print(num, 'is even')
else:
    print(num, 'is odd')
```

Comment: Zero is a perfectly fine square, though.